# Getting date automatically to sql database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

How can I automatically add a date to my database in MVC? I don't know how to get the time from my computer without manually writing it in line `c.Date = ;`. My controller:

```
        public ActionResult Add(Contact c)
        {
            bool Status = false;
            string message = "";
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                c.Date = DateTime;
                db.Contact.Add(c);
                db.SaveChanges();
                Status = true;
            }
            else
            {
                message = "Invalid Request";
            }
            ViewBag.Message = message;
            ViewBag.Status = Status;
            return View(c);
        }
```

Comment: Use [`DateTime.Now`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.datetime.now) or [`DateTime.UtcNow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.datetime.utcnow).

Comment: DateTime is a DataType, you cannot just assign it to c.Date. You want to assign a value, something like this: c = DateTime.Now. Also you need to tell us what is the Type of c.Date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just simply use DateTime class.

```
c.Date = DateTime.Now;
```

Regarding the format, you can check this site: [C# DateTime Format](https://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-format)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `DateTime.Now` property, also don't forget you can easily format the `DateTime.Now` with additional functions like `DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString()`. 
I've added it in your code:

```
public ActionResult Add(Contact c)
        {
            bool Status = false;
            string message = "";
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                c.Date = DateTime.Now;
                db.Contact.Add(c);
                db.SaveChanges();
                Status = true;
            }
            else
            {
                message = "Invalid Request";
            }
            ViewBag.Message = message;
            ViewBag.Status = Status;
            return View(c);
        }
```